# AutoHotKey: How do I check for the presence of a button with a certain label?

Tags: windows, script, autohotkey

I have two Windows which have the same window class and title texts.  The only difference are some buttons that are on one but not the other.  Using AutoHotKey, how can I check for the presence of a button, given it's label (text)?  The button's window class is not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use ImageSearch to check for the presence of buttons.

```
WinGetPos, , , Width, Height, A ;This gets the active window's size
Loop ;This loop searches for the button.
{
    ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 0, 0, Width, Height, %A_WorkingDir%\button.png
        If ErrorLevel = 0
        {
           Msgbox, I found the button at %FoundX% %FoundY%.
           break ;break the loop when the image is found
        }
    Sleep, 500
}
```

Comment: Neat way to do it...